# Correct Focus Management: JavaFX and Swing Interop

Tags: java, swing, focus, javafx

I've been developing Swing applications for many years, and recently tried getting my feet wet with JavaFX. Everything's been going well for the most part, but I'm having problems with inter-operating Swing and JavaFX components when it comes to focus.

Basically, is there a right way to manage focus between JavaFX and Swing? In the application I'm making, each component requests for focus in the window when the mouse enters it's bounds. Unfortunately, this makes JavaFX components like Popup freeze in place, instead of auto-hiding as it is defaulted to do when it loses focus.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
To be more clear, the Popup doesn't actually freeze, buttons and other stuff work, but TextFields become ineditable. I'm sure other controls suffer the same problem as well.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing where you might want to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post it to the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: Ah, I feared as much. Will do. Thank you jewelSea